# What does type or print name and title mean?

Tags: meaning, business-language, titles

I am filling out my articles of organization to form an LLC and in the last part it says to type or print my name and title.

I know what the type or print part means but I'm confused with what the title part means.

Answer (score 2):

The **"title part"** refers to **your legal status vis-a-vis the LLC itself**; e. g., President, Vice-President, Treasurer, Corporate Secretary, Chief Operating Officer, Member of the Board of Directors, and so forth. This distinction is very important, as Board Members and Corporate Officers may incur ***personal liability*** for their actions on behalf of the LLC.

Comment: Only if they're very careless.